# dgettext failing to translate string

Tags: c, internationalization, gettext

I'm using gettext/libintl as follows:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US");
char * result = bindtextdomain("MyApp", "/absolute/path/to/locale/dir");
assert(result);
result = dgettext("MyApp", "Test String");
```

In `/absolute/path/to/locale/dir` I have the translation file at `en_US/LC_MESSAGES/MyApp.mo`.

I'm testing this on macOS. It works on linux using `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8")`, but this doesn't work on macOS.

The result does not contain the translated string, it is the original string "Test String". What might I be missing? Is there a way I can debug dgettext?

Example project: https://mega.nz/file/uBATVKKA#O57nnKDHRELEY8m7U_dmC1OZLiK490sqgvoDRnT7wWY

---

After further investigation with `strace` on Linux, while `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8")` works, `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US")` doesn't – the `strace` output includes these lines not present when using `en_US.utf8`:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

[Full output](https://pastebin.com/YypwP4fA)

[Output using en_US.utf8](https://pastebin.com/dvcdRA88)

It appears Linux is looking for the default encoding to use in `LC_IDENTIFICATION`, but this file doesn't exist (Ubuntu 20.04.1)

Edit: After running `sudo locale-gen en_US` as suggested by [Guido Flohr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5464233/guido-flohr) the program runs as expected.

---

After further investigation with `dtruss` on macOS 10.15.7 (19H2), the `open` call was for the `en_GB` directory (my default system language) which doesn't exist, and `en_US` only works if the default language is set to `English (US)`, i.e. it appears `setlocale` can't actually change the locale, even though it returns the locale that was passed to it. This seems like a bug? I think I'll report it to Apple.

Edit: It seems `setlocale` is ignored in favour of the `LANG` environment variable in macos (`gettext` installed via Homebrew). Adding `setenv((char *)"LANG=en_US");` before `bindtextdomain` loads the correct messages file, and `dgettext` returns the translation as expected.

Comment: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US")` fails on your linux system (returns `null`). So it is a glibc problem. Can you check the output of `locale -a`? Did you try to install the locale `en_US` with `sudo locale-gen en_US`?

Comment: The language of Ubuntu settings was set to `English (United States)`. However, `locale -a` returned only `en_US.utf8` (among other languages). After running `sudo locale-gen en_US` as suggested `en_US` and `en_US.iso88591` appeared. The program then runs as expected using `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US")`. So Linux is resolved, thanks

Comment: Now macOS is resolved too (sort of). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct and works on my Mac OS and linux systems, both with `en_US` and `en_US.UTF-8`. So you are not missing anything except that you should usually use the native locale `""` in the call to `setlocale()` but you probably know that yourself:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

So, I can only answer the question how you can debug the problem.

There are basically two things that can go wrong:

First, the locale you select with `setlocale()` is not available on your system. This can be easily checked by outputting the return value of `setlocale(LC_ALL, selected_locale)`. In your test project you already do that. The call to `setlocale()` will return `NULL` if the selected locale is not available.

The second thing that can go wrong is that the translation catalog cannot be found.  This is best debugged with `strace` on GNU/Linux or `dtruss` on Mac OS:

```
$ sudo dtruss ./dgettextexample
```

Simply trace which files your program is trying to `open()` in order to get a hint for what is going wrong.

Comment: See my edits to my question – I don't know if there is anything I can do to fix either issue

Answer (score 0):

As there may be several possible causes, the GNU gettext FAQ https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/FAQ.html#integrating_noop contains a recipe for determining the cause in your environment.